Golang TCP connections randomly closing when copying data back and forth
So I have both a client side and a server side applitcation. The server side application looks like so:
package connpool

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

var Pool *ConnPool

func init() {
    Pool = NewConnPool()
}
func NewConnPool() *ConnPool {
    return &ConnPool{
        connections: make([]*Connection, 0),
    }
}

// AddConnection adds a new connection to the pool.
func (p *ConnPool) AddConnection(conn net.Conn, id, country, city string) {
    p.mu.Lock()
    defer p.mu.Unlock()
    newConn := &Connection{
        Conn:    conn,
        ID:      id,
        Country: country,
        City:    city,
    }
    p.connections = append(p.connections, newConn)
}

// GetConnection retrieves a connection from the pool.
func (p *ConnPool) GetConnection() *Connection {
    p.mu.Lock()
    defer p.mu.Unlock()
    if len(p.connections) > 0 {
        conn := p.connections[0]          // Get the first connection
        p.connections = p.connections[1:] // Remove it from the pool
        return conn
    }
    return nil
}

// StartServer starts a TCP server on the specified port and adds each incoming connection to the pool.
func (p *ConnPool) StartServer(port string) {
    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:"+port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error starting TCP server: ", err)
    }
    defer ln.Close()
    log.Println("TCP server listening on port", port)

    for {
        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error accepting connection: ", err)
            continue
        }
        log.Println("Accepted new connection from", conn.RemoteAddr().String())
        p.AddConnection(conn, "", "", "")
    }
}

// ReturnConnection returns a connection back to the pool.
func (p *ConnPool) ReturnConnection(conn *Connection) {
    log.Println("Returning connection to pool")
    p.mu.Lock()
    defer p.mu.Unlock()
    p.connections = append(p.connections, conn)
}

func (p *ConnPool) RemoveConnection(conn *Connection) {
    p.mu.Lock()
    defer p.mu.Unlock()
    for i, c := range p.connections {
        if c == conn {
            p.connections = append(p.connections[:i], p.connections[i+1:]...)
            break
        }
    }
    conn.Conn.Close()
}


Then in my handle HTTPS method I do the following:

func HandleHttps(conn net.Conn, rv *parser.ReqVars, bw *bufio.Writer) {
    internalConnection := connpool.Pool.GetConnection()
    if internalConnection == nil {
        log.Print("No internal connection available")
        bw.Write([]byte(httpstatus.Status500Error))
        bw.Flush()
        conn.Close()
        return
    }
    connectRequest := fmt.Sprintf("CONNECT %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n", rv.Req.Path, rv.Req.Path)
    if _, err := internalConnection.Conn.Write([]byte(connectRequest)); err != nil {
        bw.Write([]byte(httpstatus.Status500Error))
        bw.Flush()
        conn.Close()
        return
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)
    relay := func(dst, src net.Conn, done chan<- bool) {
        _, err := io.Copy(dst, src)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error during io.Copy: %v", err)
            done <- false
        } else {
            done <- true
        }
    }
    doneChan := make(chan bool, 2)
    go relay(internalConnection.Conn, conn, doneChan)
    go relay(conn, internalConnection.Conn, doneChan)

    if !<-doneChan || !<-doneChan {
        // If either relay reports an error, consider closing connections
        conn.Close()
        internalConnection.Conn.Close()
    } else {
        // Return the connection to the pool if everything was successful
        connpool.Pool.ReturnConnection(internalConnection)
    }
    // release the connection back to the pool
}


It writes the request to my client side connection and the client side then does the following:
package handlers

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func HandleHTTPS(c net.Conn, r *http.Request) error {
    dialer := net.Dialer{}

    conn, err := dialer.Dial("tcp", r.Host)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    response := &http.Response{
        Status:        "200 OK",
        StatusCode:    200,
        Proto:         "HTTP/1.1",
        ProtoMajor:    1,
        ProtoMinor:    1,
        Body:          ioutil.NopCloser(strings.NewReader("")),
        ContentLength: 0,
    }

    if err := response.Write(c); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    go io.Copy(conn, c)
    if _, err := io.Copy(c, conn); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}


The request is performed and the response is written back to my server. The client side opens connections like so:
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "resinetsdk/internal/handlers"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

const maxConnections = 30

func manageConnection(connectionID int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    for {
        dailer := &net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   2 * time.Second,
            KeepAlive: 19 * time.Minute,
        }
        conn, err := dailer.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9090")
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Connection %d failed to connect to server: %s", connectionID, err)
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
            continue
        }
        log.Printf("Connection %d established", connectionID)
        request, err := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(conn))
        handlers.HandleHTTPS(conn, request)
    }
}

func startTcpServer() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for i := 0; i < maxConnections; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go manageConnection(i, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait() // Wait for all go routines to complete before exiting
}

func main() {
    go startTcpServer()
    select {} // Block forever
}


these connections will then be added the server side connpool. When I freshly start the server and my server picks one of the connection that is the in pool it works great but when that exact same connection is picked again it suddenly closes the connection on the client side.
2024/04/22 21:17:12 Error during io.Copy: readfrom tcp 127.0.0.1:9090->127.0.0.1:3302: read tcp4 127.0.0.1:8080->127.0.0.1:3509: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
I want my connections to continuesly stay open and write back data back and forth and perform the request on the client side and write back the data to the server side. Nowhere in my code do I use c.Close() or conn.Close() so I do not understand what is going on.
I tried many things from setting the timeout too using a PING/PONG system. I tested with 50 connections opened to my server and I then tested those connections with Hey (https://github.com/rakyll/hey).
On the first run when the server is freshly started and loaded with fresh connections:
C:\Users\X>hey -n 1000 -c 30 -x http://6d5a9243-package-residential:ZIn9Tq80@127.0.0.1:8080 https://icanhazip.com/

Summary:
  Total:        0.7326 secs
  Slowest:      0.2348 secs
  Fastest:      0.0101 secs
  Average:      0.0169 secs
  Requests/sec: 1351.3860

  Total data:   14850 bytes
  Size/request: 15 bytes

Response time histogram:
  0.010 [1]     |
  0.033 [954]   |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  0.055 [4]     |
  0.078 [0]     |
  0.100 [24]    |■
  0.122 [5]     |
  0.145 [0]     |
  0.167 [0]     |
  0.190 [1]     |
  0.212 [0]     |
  0.235 [1]     |


Latency distribution:
  10% in 0.0113 secs
  25% in 0.0119 secs
  50% in 0.0130 secs
  75% in 0.0156 secs
  90% in 0.0202 secs
  95% in 0.0250 secs
  99% in 0.0999 secs

Details (average, fastest, slowest):
  DNS+dialup:   0.0022 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0842 secs
  DNS-lookup:   0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs
  req write:    0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0012 secs
  resp wait:    0.0146 secs, 0.0101 secs, 0.2347 secs
  resp read:    0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0005 secs

Status code distribution:
  [200] 990 responses


On the second run without changing anything:

Summary:
  Total:        60.7269 secs
  Slowest:      0.2524 secs
  Fastest:      0.0105 secs
  Average:      0.0199 secs
  Requests/sec: 16.3025

  Total data:   10320 bytes
  Size/request: 15 bytes

Response time histogram:
  0.011 [1]     |
  0.035 [650]   |■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
  0.059 [11]    |■
  0.083 [11]    |■
  0.107 [13]    |■
  0.131 [1]     |
  0.156 [0]     |
  0.180 [0]     |
  0.204 [0]     |
  0.228 [0]     |
  0.252 [1]     |


Latency distribution:
  10% in 0.0121 secs
  25% in 0.0131 secs
  50% in 0.0156 secs
  75% in 0.0193 secs
  90% in 0.0278 secs
  95% in 0.0428 secs
  99% in 0.0953 secs

Details (average, fastest, slowest):
  DNS+dialup:   0.0009 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0589 secs
  DNS-lookup:   0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs
  req write:    0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0002 secs
  resp wait:    0.0161 secs, 0.0105 secs, 0.2523 secs
  resp read:    0.0000 secs, 0.0000 secs, 0.0004 secs

Status code distribution:
  [200] 688 responses

Error distribution:
  [209] Get "https://icanhazip.com/": Internal Server Error
  [90]  Get "https://icanhazip.com/": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  [1]   Get "https://icanhazip.com/": malformed HTTP response "close"
  [2]   Get "https://icanhazip.com/": malformed HTTP status code "close"


The internal Server Error comes from the fact that the connections are not being returned to the pool when an error occurs in the io.Copy
    internalConnection := connpool.Pool.GetConnection()
    if internalConnection == nil {
        log.Print("No internal connection available")
        bw.Write([]byte(httpstatus.Status500Error))
        bw.Flush()
        conn.Close()
        return
    }


An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host: that could indicate an application protocol error on your part, but connection resets are a fact of life, and you certainly can’t return a reset connection to the pool. It’s not clear what you’re asking.
